# Can't set alarm without putting thread to sleep

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app with two activities: The first activity has a Send button. The second activity is displayed when Send is pressed.

As an exercise I want to have Send also set an alarm on the phone (say, at 5:30am) before starting the second activity. Here's the method that runs when the button is pressed:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    // Make alarm
    Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 5)
    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30);
    startActivity(i);
    //Thread.sleep(1000);

    // Start second activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I got the alarm-setting code from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Clock

When I run the above method, it's as if the 'Make alarm' code isn't there. Pressing Send simply starts the second activity, and no alarm is set in the clock app.

When I comment in the Thread.sleep(1000) call, the method runs as intended. Pressing Send causes the clock app to quickly flash on screen before the second activity of my app comes into the foreground. A system message appears saying "An alarm has been set for 5:30 am", and I can verify this by going into the clocks app.

What difference could the Thread.sleep(1000) call be making? When I change it to sleep for only 10 milliseconds, I get the same results as when the Thread.sleep call wasn't there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of blocking the UI Thread (it seems to me a little bit insane :P), launch the alarm intent with the built-in method [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)), and later catch the response to launch the next Activity.

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm_activity);

        findViewById(R.id.bt_alarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
                        .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 5)
                        .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this, onActivityResult never gets called. Pressing Send just opens up the alarm app and stays on that screen. I'm guessing it's because the action of setting an alarm never actually returns a result.

Comment: I tested this code before post it, and it works. have you changed something?

Comment: I ran it again but it still stays on the alarm app after pressing Send. However, calling `intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true)` makes everything run as it should, the alarm being set in the background. But that's only when using startActivityForResult. Thanks!

Comment: That said, I'm still confused about how the startup of a second activity appeared to interfere with the startup of the first. Starting up the alarm app should've occurred [in a separate process](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). So shouldn't the alarm-setting have happened in parallel with the startup of my app's second activity? How did one end up "cutting off" the other?

Comment: Of course, onActivityResult is called after come back (meaning after press back button) to the Activity. If the question has solved it, please make this answer as accepted.

Comment: I'd been pressing the top-left "back" button in the alarms app to try and get back to my app's second activity, as opposed to pressing the main back button on the phone.